# How to combine two different sql queries into one with primary key in the where clause

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have to do a function in Postgres that needs to return the results of two different queries from the same table with a where clause on the same table field which is the primary key.

The ones with same index number (aka inIndex, outIndex) are related where one is an input and the second is the output of it.

Example:

```
SELECT 
       '9' as inIndex, 
       name as inFieldName 
    from FIELDS 
    where field_id = 1000000005

UNION

SELECT 
       '10' as inIndex, 
       name as inFieldName 
    from FIELDS 
    where field_id = 1000000007;

SELECT  
       '9' as outIndex, 
       name as outFieldName 
    from FIELDS 
    where field_id = 1000000004

UNION 

SELECT  
       '10' as outIndex, 
       name as outFieldName 
    from FIELDS 
    where field_id = 1000000006;
```

Is there a way to mix both queries into one?

If not, how can I return both query results into one resultset in a pl/pgsql function?

So far I have come up with two loops, adding results in a custom type with 3 columns (index, inFiled, outField). Is there a better way do to this procedure?

Comment: Can you, please, describe the format of the output you want to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
SELECT
    '9' AS FieldIndex,
    InFields.name AS InFieldName,
    OutFields.name AS OutFieldName
FROM
    FIELDS AS InFields,
    FIELDS AS OutFields
WHERE
    InFields.field_id = 1000000005
AND OutFields.field_id = 1000000004

UNION

SELECT
    '10' AS FieldIndex,
    InFields.name AS InFieldName,
    OutFields.name AS OutFieldName
FROM
    FIELDS AS InFields,
    FIELDS AS OutFields
WHERE
    InFields.field_id = 1000000007
AND OutFields.field_id = 1000000006
```

Obviously you might need to tweak it a bit...

Comment: Thanks @stormCloud! That was exactly the query I was looking for, so simple. Working great after some changes